# Change fasta file header

Tags: python, awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a few fasta files and I want to change the headers

```
>XP_001267680.1 conserved hypothetical protein [Aspergillus clavatus NRRL 1]
MTEILARLTAPSAYRYASCEILEDYGRQLRELIAYIKQPRTTADIATAAEFLLDNLDPSLHSASY...
>XP_001267682.1 60S ribosomal protein L18 [Aspergillus clavatus NRRL 1]
MGIDLDRHHVRSTHRKAPKSENVYLQVLVKLYRFLSRRTESNFNKVVLRRLFMSRINRPPVS...
etc...
```

And I want to change the fasta file so it looks like this:

```
>Acla00001
MTEILARLTAPSAYRYASCEILEDYGRQLRELIAYIKQPRTTADIATAAEFLLDNLDPSLHSASY...
>Acla00002
MGIDLDRHHVRSTHRKAPKSENVYLQVLVKLYRFLSRRTESNFNKVVLRRLFMSRINRPPVS...
...
>Acla03871
MTEILARLTAPSAYRYASCEILEDYGRQLRELIAYIKQPRTTADIATAAEFLLDNLDPSLHSASYLF...
>Acla03872
MGIDLDRHHVRSTHRKAPKSENVYLQVLVKLYRFLSRRTESNFNKVVLRRLFMSRINRPPVSL...
```

I found this piece of code to remove everything if the line starts with > and add a new > and the organism name + a number.

```
org = 'Acla'    
os.popen("""cat %s.fa | awk '/^>/{print ">%s" ++i; next}{print}'""" % (org, org)).read()
```

I want the length of all these lines to be equal by adding zeros so the number is 5 digits or the total length of the string is 10.

Comment: [edit] your question to explain how `>XP_001267680.1 conserved hypothetical protein [Aspergillus clavatus NRRL 1]` in the input maps to `>Acla00001`  and how 4 input lines becomes 8 output lines. Also get rid of the `...`s so you provide sample input/output we could test a potential solution against. Don't assume we know where `the organism name` appears in your input - just tell us which input string you want changed to which output string(s).

Comment: It doesn't change to 8, just trying to explain that it should add 1 zero if the number is 4 digits and 4 if the number is one digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change print statement to

```
 /^>/{printf ">Acla%05d\n",++i ...
```

Comment: This gives me an error :S

cat Acla.fa | awk '/^>/{printf ">Acla%05d\n" ++i; next}{print}'
awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf(">Acla%05d
1")
 FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1

Comment: you missed the comma.